# hiding submit button using jquery function not working?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, django-forms

I have created a django crispy form. I want to hide the submit button until every field has been entered i found some solution using jQuery but it is not showing the submit button after entering every field, i need your help to proceed further.

I have added two images,
before hiding submit button and trying jquery,
[image: form without hiding the submit button]

after trying jquery the submit button is not visible even after entering every field.
[image: and another screenshot after trying.]

below are my codes for respective files,

forms.py

```
class AppForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
        class Meta:
            model = App
            fields = ('__all__')

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(AppForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.helper = FormHelper()
            self.helper.form_show_labels = False

            defualt_image_path = '/media/photo.png'
            self.fields['appicon'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = defualt_image_path
            self.fields['appicon'].widget.attrs['classs']= 'appicon-field'
            self.fields['appname'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'Apps Name', 'class':'appname-field'})
            self.fields['link'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder':'App Link','class':'link-field'})
            self.fields['category'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder':'App Category', 'class': 'catg-field'})
            self.fields['subcategory'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder':'Sub Category', 'class': 'subcatg-field'})
            self.fields['points'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder':'ADD POINTS', 'class': 'points-field'})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Function to check if all fields are filled
  function checkFields() {
    var imageInput = $('.appicon-field')[0].files.length > 0;
    var charInput1 = $('.appname-field').val().trim() !== '';
    var charInput2 = $('.link-field').val().trim() !== '';
    var charInput3 = $('.catg-field').val().trim() !== '';
    var charInput4 = $('.subcatg-field').val().trim() !== '';
    var charInput5 = $('.points-field').val().trim() !== '';

    // Show/hide submit button based on input status
    document.querySelector('.submitform-button').style.display = imageInput && charInput1 && charInput2 && charInput3 && charInput4 && charInput5 ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
  }

  // Trigger checkFields on input change
  $('.appicon-field, .appname-field, .link field, .catg-field, .subcatg-field, .points-field').on('change', function() {
    checkFields();
  });

  // Initial check on page load
  checkFields();
});
```

```css
.submitform-button {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px 75px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f3c19d;
  color: #293845;
  border: 2px solid #ec975b;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="submit-div">
  <button type="submit" class="submitform-button" id="submitform-button">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log`ing all the fields in `checkFields`? Maybe they don't get set correctly?

Comment: I see one "s" too many in `self.fields['appicon'].widget.attrs['classs']= 'appicon-field'`, this way the widget doesn't get the proper class assigned ...

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML to it to make a [mcve]

Comment: Also no need for any scripting. Just add `required` to the form elements that cannot be empty

Answer (score 0):

below is the answer please check it out.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var nameField = $('.appname-field').val().trim() !== '';
            var linkField = $('.link-field').val().trim() !== '';
            var catgField = $('.catg-field').val().trim() !== '';
            var subcatgField = $('.subcatg-field').val().trim() !== '';
            var pointsField = $('.points-field').val().trim() !== '';

            
            $('.submitform-button').toggle(nameField && linkField && catgField && subcatgField && pointsField);
        }

       
        $('.appname-field, .link-field, .catg-field, .subcatg-field, .points-field').on('input', function() {
        
            checkFields();
        });

        checkFields();
    });
```

i removed these two line from earlier

```
var imageInput = $('.appicon-field')[0].files.length > 0;

document.querySelector('.submitform-button').style.display = imageInput && charInput1 && charInput2 && charInput3 && charInput4 && charInput5 ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
```

and added this line and got the solution

```
 $('.submitform-button').toggle(nameField && linkField && catgField && subcatgField && pointsField);
```